# Descriptive word for a person that "pushes over a pushover"

Tags: phrase-requests

I am looking for a word that describes a person that "pushes over a pushover". I have now a 'manipulator', but I feel that that word carries an unnecessary strength with it. A pushover only needs a push, while a manipulator gives a shove. The word Manipulator has too much of a negative connotation surrounding it and it feels too harsh. I am not looking for it to be offensive. - a weaker term than manipulator

Comment: Are you simply looking for a weaker term than _manipulator_ or something qualitatively different (e.g. _bully_)?

Comment: Seems like it might be a duplicate of [How do you describe a person who only bullies small guys but gives in to strong guys?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/394281/191178)

Comment: Please see the description of the "word-choice" tag. What is the selection of words that you're asking us to choose from?

Comment: @Laurel — How would *bully* be acceptable to the OP if *manipulator* is already too harsh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say that the pushover was **putty in that person's hands.**

[The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/putty+in+your+hands) defines "putty in (one's) hands" as:

> Easy to control or bend to one's wishes

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure someone who pushes a pushover should get off so lightly, but you could try ***motivator***:

> **motivator** noun
>  : one that motivates or impels someone or something
>
> **impel** verb
> **1 :** to urge or drive forward or on by or as if by the exertion of strong moral pressure : force felt impelled to correct the
> misconception
> **2 :** to impart motion to : propel
>
> <sub>Source: Merriam-Webster at
> [motivator](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/motivator) and
> [impel](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impel)</sub>

All the same, it’s likely to come across as a euphemism for *manipulator* — like “motivator” in scare quotes.

(You could also look into *compeller* or *catalyst*.)

Answer (score 0):

OED

**Cherrypicker:**

> 3. colloquial (originally U.S. Railways slang). A person who selects only the best or the most profitable items, opportunities, etc. Cf. cherry-pick v.
>
> 1940   Railroad Mag. Apr. 40/2   ***Cherry picker**, switchman, so called because of red lights on switch stands. Also any railroad man who is always figuring on the best jobs and sidestepping undesirable ones* (based on the old allusion, ‘life is a bowl of cherries’).

This can also be applied to anyone who chooses the easier tasks.